# Class and Database Design for Horizontal Scaling

Tags: java, mysql, spring, architecture, horizontal-scaling

> What class and database design approach should I take to make
>   horizontally scalable Spring Java Mysql application ?

**Background**  : I have been developing projects in Spring java Mysql db from a long time. One thing i always start stumbling upon is when i have to design my application such that it can be scaled up in a horizontal manner. ’N’ number of servers having a common database ,maintaining transactions using data using common db . The problem with this is DB becomes a bottleneck and at this point, Mysql really goes out of options. Kindly help or guide me for improving this

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL can be run in a cluster as well. What about that?

Comment: Mysql is used everywhere like youtube, fb etc. Why do you think its a bottleneck?

Comment: @SMA In my design,it starts becoming a bottleneck, this is why i have mentioned a proposed design approach . Like i can use a single table which maintains lets say a common key for each request in db and then using select for update to lock the row, so that if another request from other server comes, it  can see that a request is currently on going .

Comment: @Glains I will check out Mysql cluster although i am looking for more of a combined java and db design approach solution